# Create new column with if else in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, if-statement, statistics

I have a database like this:

```
structure(list(code = c(1, 2, 3, 4), age = c(25, 30, 45, 50), 
car = c(0, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
  "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to create a column "drivers under 40" with this conditions:

- 0 if Age<40 & car==0
- 1 if Age<40 & car==1

How do I create the third column with this conditions?
I tried using the code "if else" to create a variable but it doesn't work.

```
drivers <- ifelse((age <= 40) & (car==0), 0, ifelse((age<=40) & (car==1), 1))
```

Is maybe the code written wrong?
Is there another method to do it? I am afraid to mess up the parentheses so I'd prefer another method, if there is any faster

Comment: if your data is in data frame named `df1`, you could use `df1$drivers = ifelse((df1$age <= 40) & (df1$car==0), 0, ifelse((df1$age<=40) & (df1$car==1), 1, -99))` and replace -99 with what you want in that case.

Comment: or `library(dplyr); df1 %>% mutate(drivers = 1 * (age < 40 & car == 1))` assuming you'd want zero for age >= 40 which doesn't seem to be specified.

Comment: "it doesn't work" isn't terribly specific.  Do you get an error message?  Are the results not as you expected?  Please provide details.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: @JonSpring so the -99 stands for when ifelse((df1$age<=40) & (df1$car==1), 1, -99)) is false, right?

Comment: That is right .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` version with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(drivers_under_40 = case_when(age <= 40 & car==0 ~ 0,
                                      age <= 40 & car==1 ~ 1,
                                      TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

```
  code   age   car drivers_under_40
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1    25     0                0
2     2    30     1                1
3     3    45     0               NA
4     4    50     1               NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A `base R` option

```
df1$drivers_under_40 <-  with(df1, (age <= 40 & car == 1)* NA^(age> 40))
df1$drivers_under_40
[1]  0  1 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you work with `dplyr` you have to specify the data in your ifelse statement.
data$column for example. Also you have to assign a new column for the operation.
And the last else-statement is missing.

so your ifelse statement should look like this:

```
data = structure(list(code = c(1, 2, 3, 4), age = c(25, 30, 45, 50), 
               car = c(0, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                       "tbl", "data.frame"))

data$drivers <- ifelse((data$age <= 40) & (data$car==0), 0, ifelse((data$age<=40) & (data$car==1), 1, "here you have to fill another 'else' value"))
```

Comment: Basically I would need to variable with all people under 40. Then, if they have cars, then driver=1, car is 0, then driver=0.

Comment: Also, can i create the column by using the mutate function? Or is it different?

Comment: so this would be the following ifelse statement;
`ifelse(data$age <= 40, ifelse(data$car == 1, 1, 0), 0)`

you mean tho add the column with the mutate function?
then you don't need to write data in front of every column yeah.
like this:
`data = mutate(data, drivers = ifelse(age <= 40, ifelse(car == 1, 1, 0), 0))`